# Shortest path covering certain nodes in a graph

Tags: algorithms, weighted-graphs

Consider a weighted graph where each node represents a city. Now a truck starts 
from a `city A` and it has to cover a set of cities `B, C, D`.. could be in any order
How to generate an ordering that result in the minimum total distance travelled 
while covering all the cities.

Comment: This is similar to the classic computer science problem called the "Travelling Salesman Problem". There are several variants of this problem so you need to be more specific, see the discussion under Juho's answer. Some more background would also be nice. It sounds like a homework question which may be okay, but I can't imagine the teacher didn't give more information than this. Also, don't be disappointed if someone closes this question, because there's already a lot of questions about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is NP-hard by a routine reduction, so you won't find an efficient algorithm unless P = NP. If the number of cities is not large, just try all orderings. Otherwise, you can resort to a heuristic (e.g., build the path city-by-city always picking say the one closest to your current location) or a more complex metaheuristic like a genetic algorithm.

Comment: Also, since the poster talks about "covering" all the cities, they might be fine with visiting a city more than once. Then the problem can be 1.5-approximated by computing the metric closure of the graph and restricting to the subgraph induced by the set of cities of interest. Then [Christofides algorith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm) can be used.

Comment: @Steven Good point! I'd be happy to upvote if you want to make this into an answer. I guess "ordering" was implying a permutation of nodes and thus I expected a path.

Comment: Oh, that's also true... It's unclear what the expected solution should be at this point. Perhaps @rohit can clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be the graph and let $S$ be the set of cities you want to visit.

Since you talk about "covering" all the cities, it might be the case that you are fine with visiting cities more than once as long as all cities in $S$ are visited at least once. The problem is still NP-hard in this case (see Juho's answer), but it can be 1.5-approximated using [Christofides algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm).

To do so you can first compute the metric closure $G'$ of $G$ ($G'$ is a complete graph and the weight of a generic edge $(u,v)$ is the weight of the shortest path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$).
Then, you can restrict yourself to the subset of cities of interest, i.e., you can consider the subgraph $H = G'[S]$ of $G'$ induced by the vertices in $S$.

Clearly the weight $w^*$ of an optimal tour is the same on both $G$ and $H$.
By running Christofides algorithm on $H$ you obtain a tour $T$ of weight at most $1.5w^*$.
The tour $T$ can be converted back to a tour on $G$ by replacing each edge $(u,v)$ of $T$ with the shortest path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$. This doesn't change the cost of $T$.